# Keycloak state parameter invalid

Tags: keycloak

When user clicks login, redirected to Keycloak login page & then after successful login, user comes back to application with 400 error page.
Server log shows following:

> [Server:node-00] 13:40:00,709 WARN 
>   [org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator] (default task-30)
>   state parameter invalid

My application conf is:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
    <secure-deployment name="appWEB.war">
        <realm>demo</realm>
        <resource>app</resource>
        <public-client>true</public-client>
        <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8180/auth</auth-server-url>
        <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
    </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>
```

Application URL is https://localhost:8443/app & redirect_url is  https://localhost:8443/app/private.jsf.

When I use http, it works. But the error comes when I use same with https.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here it can be many scenario which may failing with `https`

1. Keycloak running in `https`
2. Create self sign certification for keycloak.
3. Import this certificate to your local Java environment.SO handshake can be possible.

I hope you generate the certificates in keycloak you can find the the certificate inside `keycloak/security/ssl`.

Comment: Keycloak is running in HTTP.

Comment: Why keycloak running in `http`? Keycloak should run on `https` only. Keycloak running in `http ` and application running on `https`?

Comment: Yes, it's development env to check KC.